# Property 'isMulti' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & UserSelectProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a component which looks like so:

```
      <Controller
        name="members"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <UserSelect
            accountId={accountId}
            label="Project Members"
            isMulti
            {...field}
          />
        )}
      />
```

and it is giving me the following TS error (red squiggly on `isMulti`):

`Type '{ onChange: (...event: any[]) => void; onBlur: Noop; value: any; name: "members"; ref: RefCallBack; accountId: string; label: string; isMulti: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & UserSelectProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'. Property 'isMulti' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & UserSelectProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)`

full component can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/pivcec/ea9714410f2baaaf9600a28091e9f6b7

`UserSelect` component can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/pivcec/cb2645bf672324f990b27f6cd597dfcc

Comment: The error message is clear: `isMulti` is not a prop of UserSelect. You must extend or intersect with the props of the Select component if you want to expose all its props.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right that it's clear. ```type UserSelectProps = {
  accountId: string;
  label: string;
  hideSelectedOptions?: boolean;
  isClearable?: boolean;
  isMulti: any;
};``` is what I ended up using with `UserSelect` in order to clear the error

Comment: Sounds like it's probably better as a boolean rather than "any"

Comment: my bad, you're right.. had already corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend another component you can just intersect the props of Select. I believe this is from `react-select`, but the simplest way to it would be like so:

```js
type UserSelectProps = {
  accountId: string;
  label: string;
} & Parameters<typeof Select>[0];
// need to index 0, since that is props, 1 is context
```

Also react.forwardComponent is a generic component so the correct pattern would be something like this:

```js
const UserSelect = React.forwardRef<UserSelectProps["ref"], Omit<UserSelectProps, "ref>">((props, ref) => {
  //...
})
// the first type parameter is the refType and the second is the propsType
```

IIRC `react-select` props type is generic, so this might be more useful like so:

```js
import { GroupBase } from "react-select";

type UserSelectProps<
  Option = unknown,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
> = {
  accountId: string;
  label: string;
  // This requires TS4.7^ VVV, instantiation expression
} & Parameters<typeof Select<Option, IsMulti, Group>[0];

// Since you didn't provide a sandbox I just wrote this of the top of my head,
// so this may or may not work...
const UserSelect = React.forwardRef(...) as <
  Option = unknown,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
>(props: UserSelectProps<Select, IsMulti, Group>) => JSX.Element
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a lot of in depth info. I've moved on with my simple solution described in comments but will mark your answer correct since it really gets into detail.